# How to reuse the same code block at the beginning of JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp

My company are using JSP, and they have almost the same logic at almost every page that get data from session and assign it to some variable so that I can use to render page and pass to JavaScript functions. I am wondering if I can refactor to make it less "copy and paste"

Like:

```
<%
String attr1= (String) session.getAttribute("attr1");//

boolean isEnglishVersion = "en".equals(session.getAttribute("Lang"));//Get lang version, needed when rendering page

MobileGameMeta meta= (MobileGameMeta) session.getAttribute("meta");

String strFieldId = request.getParameter("id");

MobileGameField field = //use attr1 and meta to build this field, this is needed when call JavaScript function

JSONObject parameters = HTTPUtil.parseParameterMap2JSONObject((Map<String, String[]>) request.getParameterMap()); //needed when call JavaScript function

%>
```

This variable are needed at the following of my page, while every page will have the almost the same code block. How to reuse it?

In java class, I can define some fields and initiate them in constructors, do I have similar way in JSP?

Comment: Write, and use, a [custom tag](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnalk.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know that this doesn't answer your question directly, but you shouldn't be writing java code / interacting with session in a JSP. JSP is a **display** technology, and should be used only for display.

The answer is to expose these values to your JSPs via a servlet.
If you're not already using a framework that does this as part of it's standard usage pattern, find one and learn it. Spring MVC is very good, Struts will work, and there are several others that you might investigate (Google is your friend).

Then, in your JSPs, use tag libraries to display values exposed by the servlets, and stay away from writing java code in your JSPs unless you absolutely need to (and you almost never need to).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Sadly, the legacy code exists for years, I am just curious if I can easily refactor it into another way without breaking the current core logic.

Comment: As Elliot commented, write a custom JSP Tag, and use it in each page.

Answer (score 0):

As @GreyBeardedGeek said Spring/Struts is the best option but your code is exists almost for years and you can't just migrate to Spring or Struts so there is another option you can try `SiteMesh` filter. This is something like master page in Java.

Download library: http://goo.gl/6uzwCJ

Create page say `master.jsp` in directory `template` and with in body tag add you common logic that you don't want to copy paste.

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.opensymphony.com/sitemesh/decorator" prefix="decorator"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt" prefix="fn" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
   <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title><decorator:title/></title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <decorator:body/>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now create `decorators.xml` file in WEB-INF folder as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<decorators defaultdir="/template">
    <decorator name="main" page="master.jsp">
       <pattern>/Folder_name/*</pattern>
       <pattern>/Folder_name2/test.jsp</pattern>
    </decorator>
</decorators>
```

- defaultdir : Path of template/master page
- page : Template/master page that will be applied to pages
- /Folder_name/* : The URL pattern (Directory) on which the template/master page will be applied.if we use /* so all request pages pass through the template and it'll be applied to all page.
- /Folder_name2/test.jsp : Template/master page will render only test.jsp file of Folder_name2 directory. Other file will be displayed as normal page.

Configure the `web.xml` file. Append the below code in `web.xml` file.

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.opensymphony.sitemesh.webapp.SiteMeshFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>sitemesh</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

- /* : Template applied to all page extension.
- /.html : Template applied to only on html page.